# iOS Swift: Use UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout or UICollectionViewFlowLayout to create a staggered grid with automatic item height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have to create a "Staggered" grid without having to manually calculate the heights because the items of my grid are really complex (they can have multiple sub views with labels) and full of text.

The grid can have more then 2 columns.

Here there are two examples of staggered grid from Android:

[image: Creating staggered Card in android] [image: Android Tip: Staggered Grid view by RecyclerView]

I tried with UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout or UICollectionViewFlowLayout but I haven't found a way to get an optimized result.

This is the code I tried:

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(50))
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(50))
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 2)

let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

And I got this result:

[image]

Instead I was hoping to get this:

[image]

Is there a way to create a staggered UICollectionView (grid) with auto heights and multiple columns on iOS with Swift?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is possible to achieve the desired layout - with ``UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`` you could use ``estimated`` dimensions for height of items and groups, which will be based on contents of the cells. Please add code you've tried.

Comment: @ViktorGavrilov I added the code I've tried. Thank you so much!

Comment: I was wrong, ``UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`` is forcing one height for the whole group, so if you need several columns in one group, you still need to calculate heights manually to provide .fractionalHeight for each item (as shown here https://zenn.dev/ikeh1024/articles/5eb702b698b9c8)

Comment: @ViktorGavrilov Unfortunately I have already seen that tutorials. Thank you for your time!

Comment: you got the answer? please help me if you have answer.

Comment: Now I'm using SwiftUI. Search for SwiftUI staggered grid. There are a lot of examples. Like this one: https://github.com/spacenation/swiftui-grid